# Horizontal menu hide first list style and show the rest

Tags: css, html-lists

I got this problem which i can't figure out.

```
#menuUL{    
    font-size:32px;
    padding:0;
}

#menuUL li:first-child{
    list-style-type: none;  
}

#menuUL li{
    margin-left:30px;
    /*display: list-item;*/
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:disc;
}
```

I have a horizontal menu, but i only want the first item to hide it's list style type, the rest needs to show the disc. However then i will put 2 display's in the same li which causes it to display vertically instead of horizontal.

UPDATE.
the html code

```
<div id="photoMenu">
<ul id="menuUL">
    <li>ALL</li>
    <li>ARCHITECTURE</li>    
    <li>PEOPLE</li>
    <li>LEGO</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you show some html also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try floating the `li` instead

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XLj2j/2/)

**CSS**

```
#menuUL{    
    font-size:32px;
    padding:0;
}

#menuUL > li:first-of-type {
    list-style-type: none;  
}

#menuUL li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:35px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it work's now only need to center it now. Do you have have a tip for that?